# How to transition from front-end to back-end as a developer?

Tags: career-development, career-switch

I'm not sure if this site is fit to ask such a question, but still gonna ask.
So I'm currently working as a Front-end engineer, I have around 1.5 years of professional working experience. For a year I worked using Vue, then I transitioned to Android development and currently working in this field. But I feel that it's not for me (front-end) and want to move to back-end development. So the question is: Is it possible to get a job as a junior back-end developer without any relevant experience? Since most of the back-end positions require Mid or Senior level of technicality. I know Java okay(5 out of 10), know some Python, and SQL at the level of writing simple queries (Postgresql), and have a good understanding of networking. I could learn some frameworks such as Spring, but even if I get comfortable with it and perhaps do some projects for my portfolio, am I able to find a job later with what I have? Or I should stick with the front-end for couple more years and then transition? Does it make sense now to quit the front-end and go deep with learning the back-end stack? Is there any path that someone could share? Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Why don't you ask your team if you could pick up some back-end work to start learning a new skill? Finding a new position in an area you're completely unfamiliar with is not easy. At your current company you could start learning and contributing.

Comment: @xxbbcc I tried to, didn't work. The team lead says I need at least two-three years of frontend experience. But they offered to help me with any question if I learned by myself the back-end (so not giving actual projects)

Comment: What is your education level? I see very little problems if you have a BSc in CS, but I do see problems if all you have is a 6 week "coding in JS bootcamp".

Comment: @nvoigt I have a BSc in CS

Answer (score 3):

if i were you then..

1. i would prepare my resume with java, spring, sql as experience
2. Go to Coursera/ unacademy/ edureka get conversant take courses on these technologies. Take frequent leaves from office.
3. apply jobs take interviews. See what I was not able to answer in previous interview and patch-it-up. Eventually i will find backend job.

I am assuming that you made up your mind to go backend. Please be advised that backend is not a green meadow.

Comment: What do you mean by 'i would prepare my resume with java, spring, sql as experience' ? How to prepare something as experience? Pet projects are enough?

Comment: No. You have some experience, say 1.5y. say that in your resume that you worked on `spring` in last `1.5y` ; nobody checks (even in background verification) if worked on particular technology for last `1.5y`